# TypeScript 'target' and Babel

Tags: typescript, webpack, ecmascript-5, babeljs, tsconfig

I'm using `TypeScript` with `Webpack`, and i have question about transpiling `TypeScript` code to `ES5` code.

If I understand correctly, I don't need any babel loader, if I set `target` option (in `tsconfig.json`) to `ES5`? Right?

If not, so where are the differences?

Answer (score 6):

The answer is: it depends. It depends on which features of ES6 you are going to use. TypeScript deals with most of them and compiles to ES5 fine, but there are some exceptions, for example: for..of loops. for..of loops are the ES6 feature that is based on iterators. For every object you can define a method and put it under the key called `[Symbol.iterator]` and this method will be used by for..of loop to iterate over the object. You can find more info [for example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html). However, if you set TypeScript target to ES5 this will not work. This is because in case of ES5 TypeScript will compile the loop to the basic for loop, assuming that the object you iterate over has an explicit `length` property and is integer-indexed (like an array). Look at the example:

```
for (const a of someObject) {
 //some operations
}
```

if you set target to ES5 this will be compiled into

```
for (var _i = 0; _i < someObject.length; _i++) {
  var a = someObject[_i];
  //some operations
}
```

which *requires* you to provide both `length` and integer properties from `0` to `length-1` on that object. This is kind of opposed to the idea of iterators, which in ES6 lets you freely define how you want to iterate over the object.

So to sum up: if you plan to use ES6 features in your ES5-targetted TypeScript code, make sure what they are going to be compiled to. In case there are some limitations on the outputting code, set target to ES6 and use Babel on the result.